# Best way to select values from a Dataframe based off of criteria in a column?

Tags: python, pandas

So I have a big dataframe with a column FundID. In this column is a number of FundIDs but i only want some of them. This value is not the index but I can make it the index if that is easier.

Currently I am using df.loc[] to select values in each column but I'm thinking there has to be a better way. Any suggestions?

```
 reader.loc[(reader['ABOR Fund ID']==770) | (reader['ABOR Fund ID']==113) | 
(reader['ABOR Fund ID']==127)|(reader['ABOR Fund ID']==533)|(reader['ABOR 
 Fund ID']==4094)|(reader['ABOR Fund ID']==79)|(reader['ABOR Fund 
 ID']==735)|(reader['ABOR Fund ID']==1684)|(reader['ABOR Fund ID']==91)| 
(reader['ABOR Fund ID']==1194)|(reader['ABOR Fund ID']==2015)|(reader['ABOR 
 Fund ID']==1530)|(reader['ABOR Fund ID']==72)|(reader['ABOR Fund 
ID']==737)|(reader['ABOR Fund ID']==738)|(reader['ABOR Fund ID']==628)]
```

Comment: It seems like you can use `reader.loc[reader['ABOR Fund ID'].isin([770, 113, 127])]` ...

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
reader.loc[reader['ABOR Fund ID'].isin([values seperated by comma])]
```